# Parsing strings into different types with common error message in GO

Tags: go, error-handling

I want parse `[]string` values into particular types (e.g. int, float etc), so I must use different parse functions for different lines. My code:

```golang
value, err := strconv.Atoi(line[1])
value1, err := strconv.ParseFloat(line[4], 6)
value2, err := strconv.ParseFloat(line[5], 6)
value3, err := strconv.Atoi(line[2])
```

I must be sure that every value was parsed so for every value I must have `err != nil`. Is there any approach to make it with one common error without

```golang
if err != nil {
 return 
}
```

after each line?

Comment: "Is there any approach to make it without [...] after each line?" No.

Comment: to make code cleaner, you can abstract the error check part in a function and just call them to parse.

Comment: So there was such possibility (sscanf). IMHO thread with errors handling techniques is only related to my question, not duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fmt.Sscanf do do this with one error check:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i int
    var j float64
    var k int
    if _, err := fmt.Sscanf("1,3.14,5", "%d,%f,%d", &i, &j, &k); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(i, j, k)
}
```

You'll need to join the lines with some separator but that's trivial.

Also, there's a discussion about making handling of multiple errors nicer for Go 2, I'm not sure what the status of it is at the moment, but you can read about it here: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-error-handling-overview.md

Comment: Sscanf works great, draft looks really promising, thanks for sharing